# Python: filter dataFrame with keep only last data by ActiveFlag and Date

Tags: python, dataframe, filter, group-by, apply

I have sorted by `Date` and `ID` dataset (`df`):

```
Date          ID      Start_flag    End_flag                               
01-01-2019    100     1             0     
01-02-2019    100     0             0
01-03-2019    100     0             0
01-04-2019    100     0             0
01-05-2019    100     0             1
01-09-2019    100     1             0 
01-10-2019    100     0             0
01-11-2019    100     0             0
01-12-2019    100     0             0
01-03-2019    500     1             0     
01-04-2019    500     0             0
01-05-2019    500     0             0
01-06-2019    500     0             0
01-07-2019    500     0             0
01-08-2019    500     0             0 
01-09-2019    700     1             0
01-10-2019    700     0             0
01-11-2019    700     0             1
```

I would like to filter `df` by last actual `Date`, where `Start_flag`=1 appears, all data that was before for the same `ID` with the `Start_flag`=1 shouldn't be extracted.

Other words, if there are a few times happens `Start_flag=1` for the same `ID` then keep only the last `Start_flag=1` with the max `Date`.

Expected view of `df` is:

```
Date          ID      Start_flag    End_flag                               
01-09-2019    100     1             0 
01-10-2019    100     0             0
01-11-2019    100     0             0
01-12-2019    100     0             0
01-03-2019    500     1             0     
01-04-2019    500     0             0
01-05-2019    500     0             0
01-06-2019    500     0             0
01-07-2019    500     0             0
01-08-2019    500     0             0 
01-09-2019    700     1             0
01-10-2019    700     0             0
01-11-2019    700     0             1
```

I tries to do it by `.groupby(['ID','Start_flag'])['Date'].last()`, but it's not correct approach.

Could you please help me how can I filter extra Data from `df`? Thanks

**EDIT:**
possible solution is:

```
def filterTable(df):
    result_list = []
    for x in df['ID'].unique():
        df_1 = df[df['ID']==x]
        indx = df_1.where(((df_1['Start_flag']==0) & (df_1['Date']==df_1['Date'].min())) | (df_1['Start_flag'] == 1)).last_valid_index()
        result_list.append(df_1.loc[indx:])   
    result= pd.concat(result_list)
    return result
```

The condition `df_1['Start_flag']==0` is added due to return the `last_valid_index` for the cases when initially `Start_flag=0` till to `End_flag=1`

Furthermore, it's not optimal solution due to time execution for huge dataFrame. Try to find the better solution for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not pythonic

```
result = []
for i in df['ID'].unique():
    adf = df[df['ID'] == i].sort_values(by="Date").reset_index(drop=True)
    i = adf.where(adf['Start_flag'] == 1).last_valid_index()
    result.append(adf.iloc[range(i, len(adf))])   
print (pd.concat(result).reset_index(drop=True))
```

Output:

```
         Date   ID  Start_flag  end
0  2019-01-09  100           1    0
1  2019-01-10  100           0    0
2  2019-01-11  100           0    0
3  2019-01-12  100           0    0
4  2019-01-03  500           1    0
5  2019-01-04  500           0    0
6  2019-01-05  500           0    0
7  2019-01-06  500           0    0
8  2019-01-07  500           0    0
9  2019-01-08  500           0    0
10 2019-01-09  700           1    0
11 2019-01-10  700           0    0
12 2019-01-11  700           0    1
```

**Note**: We can avoid the loop by moving the logic to a function and calling the function via `apply` over the `groupby`. However, the `groupby` runs the function twice on the fist group, so we have to make sure our function is free of side effect.

Using groupby:

```
def fun(adf):
    adf = adf.sort_values(by="Date").reset_index(drop=True)
    i = adf.where(adf['Start_flag'] == 1).last_valid_index()
    return adf.iloc[range(i, len(adf))]

print (df.groupby('ID').apply(fun).reset_index(drop=True))
```

Comment: thank you for you help and idea. I tried to validate in works as well. But only one strange error appears when tried to apply of full dataset: `'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`. I'm still exploring why there is happened `Nonetype` in `iloc`?!  variable `i`- is an integer and `len(df)` is also integer, that's what usage of `range` needs.

Comment: I fixed it by usage:`adf.loc[i:]` for each groups. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Final corrected Solution is:

```
def validateData(adf):  
    adf = adf.sort_values(by="Date").reset_index(drop=True)
    indx = adf.where(((adf['Start_flag']==0) & (adf['Date']==adf['Date'].min())) | (adf['Start_flag'] == 1)).last_valid_index()

    return adf.iloc[range(indx, len(adf))]

def filterData(df):
    start_time = datetime.now()
    print('Start_time=', start_time)
    RESULT_DF = df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: validateData(x))
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (datetime.now() - start_time))
    return RESULT_DF
```

To apply on data:
`RESULT_DF = filterData(df)`